# Dynamic Linq .OrderBy in VB.Net not accepting strings

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem implementing Scott G's Dynamic.vb extension at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx in my vb solution.  I know there are probably other ways, but this approach would give me such great flexibility.  I've searched StackOverflow (80+ Q&As) and numerous other sites without much luck.  I'm using VS 2010.

I've included Dynamic.vb in a problem with no root namespace, and then added a reference to that project in my main one.  I'm getting intellisense for 4 overloads (rather than 2) so I'm pretty certain that the extension is in scope.

I was having a tough time with clauses, especially the OrderBy as Scott demonstrated.  If I simply pass a string as Scott's VB example did I get the error "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OrderBy' can be called with these arguments."

The line of code is:

```
Dim FilteredComponentList = From Component As MX.Component In ComponentList.AsQueryable _
                                    .OrderBy("Name")
```

So I found other references that stated to pass a Lambda expression.  So I tried this and at least I get no error, even if the sort function still doesn't seem to work.  Here is the code that compiles and executes.

```
    Private Sub SortByColumn()

        If Not cmbComponentFilter.SelectedItem.ToString = "All" Then
            Dim FilteredComponentList = From Component As MX.Component In ComponentList.AsQueryable _
                               Where Component.ComponentType.ToString = cmbComponentFilter.SelectedItem.ToString _
                               Order By Component.Name

            Dim OrderedFilteredComponentList = From Component As MX.Component In FilteredComponentList.AsQueryable _
                                               .OrderBy(Function(str) dgvComponents.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)

            bsComponentList.DataSource = OrderedFilteredComponentList
            dgvComponents.DataSource = bsComponentList
        Else
            Dim FilteredComponentList = From Component As MX.Component In ComponentList.AsQueryable _
                                        .OrderBy(Function(str) dgvComponents.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)

            bsComponentList.DataSource = FilteredComponentList
            dgvComponents.DataSource = bsComponentList

        End If

    End Sub
```

When I interrogate the dgvComponents.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name it gives the objects property I wish to sort by, but the sort still isn't working.  I'm concerned why I can't get Scott's implementation to work, but I've heard his keynotes and read his blogs, so I'm guessing the problem lies with my implementation.

I'd like either to work but need to understand why as well.  Why doesn't passing a string work? Isn't the PARAMARRAY declared in the function optional?  I've gotten 8 hours invested in this, and while I could go down other paths, I'm too committed to finding the answer to this approach to give up (suicide pact with an approach.)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  I'm so demoralized that it wouldn't even bother me if it was a silly mistake (which it often is.)

Thanks for any assistance.

r/Jamie

Comment: I think you need something like `Function(str) str.Name`

Comment: Thanks Alvin. The dgvComponents is a datagridview that is bound to an observable collection. When you click the column header, this statement: <pre><code> dgvComponents.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name) </code></pre> returns the object bound property name.  This would be analogous to added an <pre><code> Order By objComponent.Name</code></pre> where Name is the column header you clicked on.  In debug, I can see that this portion of the statement is returning the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm an idiot.  I forgot to include:

```
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic
```

In the class using the extension.  Now that I've done that, this works without the lambda express.  New code that works follows, Lambda's not required:

```
    Private Sub SortByColumn()

    If cmbComponentFilter.SelectedItem.ToString <> "All" Then
        Dim FilteredComponentList = From Component As MX.Component In ComponentList.AsQueryable _
                           Where Component.ComponentType.ToString = cmbComponentFilter.SelectedItem.ToString

        Dim OrderedFilteredComponentList = From Component As MX.Component In FilteredComponentList.AsQueryable _
                                           .OrderBy(dgvComponents.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)

        bsComponentList.DataSource = OrderedFilteredComponentList
        dgvComponents.DataSource = bsComponentList
    Else
        Dim FilteredComponentList = From Component As MX.Component In ComponentList.AsQueryable _
                                    .OrderBy(dgvComponents.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name)

        bsComponentList.DataSource = FilteredComponentList
        dgvComponents.DataSource = bsComponentList

    End If

End Sub
```

Now that I have the extensions working, I think this approach will add a lot of value and reduce the coding effort to dynically select, sort, filter, etc data based upon user selections.  I hope my troubles might assist others at my level to better understand how to make this work in vb.net.